# C# Project compiles quickly, but then VS becomes unresponsive

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I've got a problem that's driving me nuts. We have a C# project that has a few types of custom controls, but has several hundred instances of those controls (don't ask). Every time I do anything that requires compile I get the following behavior:

- The project appears to build very quickly (like 3 or 4 seconds).
- Then VS becomes totally unresponsive for quite a while (maybe 15 seconds to a minute)

The status at the bottom of the window shows "Build Succeeded" during the unresponsive period. 
Clicking just about anything will cause a spinner to appear.
Eventually the spinner will go away and the status will show "Ready" at the bottom, at which point I'm back in business.

I'm almost certain that this is a self-inflicted problem, but for the life of me I can't figure out what is going on during the "spinning" period. Is there any way to see what's going on during the build process so that I can determine precisely how I'm shooting myself in the foot?

UPDATE: I tried a strange experiment. I created a new application using the exact same user controls and then just plopped down about 2,000 of them on my form. No problem at all, this application works fine. How incredibly odd...

Comment: Maybe Visual Studio is reloading design-time functionality for the custom controls that were rebuilt. If you don't modify the controls frequently, separate them in their own project and build that project only when needed. Of course, reference this new 'custom controls' project from the original project.

Comment: +1 for @Mzn. We have most of our user controls outside our executable projects. Not only does it make things quicker, it forces a more rigourous separation of the controller (in the exe) from the view (in the user control library) - which is no bad thing OMHO

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I had already tried putting the custom controls into their own project. I even went as far as linking to the dll (as opposed to including a project reference) to avoid any problems with recompiling the dll...no difference!

Comment: try compiling using the msbuild command line, that would at least isolate irreducible compilation issues from how you are using visual studio issues.

Comment: You can check to see if it is related to refreshing the toolbox by temporarily setting Tools/Options/Windows Forms Designer/AutoToolBoxPopulate to false.

Comment: Other Visual Studio projects run normally fine and faster that are similiar in size?

Comment: Thanks for the msbuild suggestion, it's interesting. msbuild executes rapidly (less than a second). However if I do the msbuild and then go back to Studio...presto, it's back into "spinning unresponsive" mode for a while, after which it recovers. This really smells like some problem with the designer instantiating the custom controls.

Comment: sgmoore: thanks, I had already set AutoToolBoxPopulate to false, but it was a good idea!

Comment: Check your build settings and see if there are any post-build steps.  I worked with a project once where someone had put an xcopy step after the build that ran quite slowly.

Comment: You've got a debugger, don't be afraid to use it ;)  Start another instance of VS, use Tools + Attach to Process to attach the debugger to the first one.  Use Debug + Break All when it goes catatonic and poke in Debug + Windows + Threads.  The call stacks of them ought to give a hint.  Resume and break a few times to look for a repeat.

Comment: That's a really interesting idea, however it's using Visual Studio to debug Visual Studio. Since I don't have the source code to VS it just shows all the worker threads, but the call stack shows "External Code". Bonus points for a darned clever idea though!

Answer (score 0):

Close the form design view before compiling the project.

If that did not work (which worked for me but not for you as you've mentioned in your comment) then I think it's something about your custom control like trying to connect to a server and validating it's licensing. Check your internet traffic with something like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). I hope that helps.

Comment: Good suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't work. I tried closing every single open file prior to compiling and the behavior is the same.

Comment: Huh...controls can connect to a server? Interesting....think I'll whip out Wireshark and take a look!

Comment: Hmm...doesn't appear to be network related. Wireshark doesn't show anything that pops out at me (although filtering Wireshark can be an interesting exercise at times).

Comment: Then what are you experiencing here is different than mine. Just one other thing: Is there any difference between behavior of Build and Rebuild? If so then it's about size of your project and maybe NGen is being called somewhere.

Comment: As long as anything actually compiles, then the problem occurs. I just noticed something interesting: if I do a "rebuild" then VS remains responsive (I can open up files, etc) UNTIL the build succeeded message shows up...at which point it goes into spinning-unresponsive mode. Clearly Studio is doing something after the compile, but it's hard to figure out what that is!